# How to catch and disallow "fullscreen" (green) button on OSX 10.7+?

Tags: macos, fullscreen, osx-yosemite, nswindow

I was using the following code to change the size and contents of the windows.

```
- (BOOL)windowShouldZoom:(NSWindow *)window toFrame:(NSRect)newFrame{

    [self switchToOtherSize];
    return NO;
}
```

Now, the green button makes the app fullscreen and this code does not work anymore as the green button does no longer "Zoom" by default.

I couldn't find a similar delegate to catch the click action on the green button and "return NO".

Is there a way to do this?

I tried the following, it works but throws an ugly exception which says that the method should return a value that includes "Fullscreen".

```
-(NSApplicationPresentationOptions)window:(NSWindow *)window willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions:(NSApplicationPresentationOptions)proposedOptions{
    [self switchToOtherSize];

    return NSApplicationPresentationDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, this will work (10.10 & 10.11):

```
[self.window setCollectionBehavior: NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
```

Comment: This worked for me as well.  The new behavior is explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#10_11Window  -->  "NSWindow will implicitly opt certain candidate windows into becoming full screen capable."  It's sort of annoying given that I have an aspect ratio constraint on the window that's being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow your window to go full-screen, do not include `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary` in the window's `collectionBehavior`. In Interface Builder, there's a "Full Screen" pop-up menu on the window's Attributes inspector, which you can set to Unsupported.

When that's disabled, the green button goes back to being the Zoom button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked that pop-up menu and it's already set to "Unsupported". Then changed it to other values and back again to see if there is a problem with taking that settings, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you modifying the window's `collectionBehavior` programmatically? If you Option-click the green button, or select Zoom from the Window menu, does the window behave as you want? Is your `-windowShouldZoom:toFrame:` method called in that case?

Comment: I do not call anything related to collectionBehavior programmatically. If I option-click the green button, it turns into Zoom and my method is called.

Comment: You could try logging the window's `collectionBehavior`. You could also try `window.collectionBehavior &= ~NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary;`. Cocoa really shouldn't allow the window to go full-screen if it doesn't have that collection behavior.

Comment: Haven't you mixed terms full screen(what you have now) and full screen size (unsupported)? I tried and menu bar with dock remains visible. You have to use autolayot with max size of window or use maximum size of window without autolayout